# Link to a saved variable ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that's called `item` and inside of it there's a field `gender` with values `female` / `male` I've created on a dropdown.

My question is how do I link it back to just listing the items under the `item.gender = female`?

I want it to be something like this `<% link_to items_path(gender = "Female") %>`

Comment: What have you done so far? There is plenty of room here, please post your code. You'll be more likely to get an answer if you supply some code. There are a million ways to do things in Ruby and Rails people aren't likely to spend a ton of time coding an answer that is based on something different than what you already have. Unless you are just looking for the logic rather than an actual code answer, then you should specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add this functionality through your Items controller.

You can do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Female Items", female_items_path %>
```

and in your routes.rb file:

```
'items/female' => 'items#female', as: :female_items
```

and in your Items Controller:

```
def female
  @items = Item.find_by gender: 'female' 
end
```

and then you can iterate over the @items object in your items/female view:

```
<% items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.title %>
  ...(insert whatever values your items have that you want to display)
<% end %>
```